# Coding node.js without restarting the "server"

Tags: node.js, meteor

I've been playing with Meteor (you probably know it's a node.js framework), and really like how you can start it up, and then leave it running while code updates are implemented automatically upon saving.

Is there a way I can do this just running node.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)? It's almost the same you are looking for.